# How to compare asymptotic distribution of MLE and OLS estimators?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, parameter-estimation, positive-semidefinite

I have the following problem on my Statistics Problem Set:

> Consider the model
>   \begin{equation*}
> y_{i}=x_{i}^{\prime }\beta +u_{i},
> \end{equation*}
>   where $\left( x_{i}^{\prime },u_{i}\right) $ are iid with $u_{i}|x_{i}$ have
>   the density $f\left( u\right) \in C^{2}$ (with support $-\infty <u<\infty $
>   ). Assume that
>   \begin{eqnarray*}
> E\left( U\right) &=&\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }uf\left( u\right) =0\text{ and}
> \\
> V\left( U\right) &=&E\left( U^{2}\right) =\int_{-\infty }^{\infty
> }u^{2}f\left( u\right) =\sigma ^{2}.
> \end{eqnarray*}
>
> a)Use transformation of variables to show that the (conditional) pdf of $
> y_{i}|x_{i}$ is given by $g\left( y_{i}|x_{i}\right) =f\left(
> y_{i}-x_{i}^{\prime }\beta \right) $.
>
> b) Find the likelihood of $y=\left( y_{1},...,y_{n}\right) $ conditional
>   on $X=\left( x_{1},...,x_{n}\right) ^{\prime }$.
>
> c) State the Gauss-Markov theorem.
>
> d) We will show in item (f) that the asymptotic variance of$\sqrt{n}(%
> \widetilde{\beta }-\beta ^{\ast })$ can be smaller than the asymptotic
>   variance of $\sqrt{n}(\widehat{\beta }-\beta ^{\ast })$, where $\widetilde{%
> \beta }$ is the MLE and $\widehat{\beta }$ is the OLS estimator. Explain why
>   this result does not contradict the Gauss-Markov theorem.
>
> e) Find the asymptotic variance of$\sqrt{n}(\widehat{\beta }-\beta ^{\ast
> })$.
>
> f) Show algebraically that (i) the asymptotic variance of$\sqrt{n}(%
> \widetilde{\beta }-\beta ^{\ast })$ is no larger than the asymptotic
>   variance of $\sqrt{n}(\widehat{\beta }-\beta ^{\ast })$; and (ii) give a
>   necessary and sufficient condition on the density $f\left( u\right) $ for
>   the asymptotic variance of $\widehat{\beta }$ and $\widetilde{\beta }$ to be
>   the same.

I'm fine with this problem until item f).

I was able to do it all, including computing the asymptotic distributions:

$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta} - \beta ^{\ast }) \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \sigma^2(x^T x)^{-1})$

$\sqrt{n}(\tilde{\beta} - \beta ^{\ast
}) \xrightarrow{d}N\Bigg(0, \Bigg[\mathbb{E}\Big(x_i \bigg(\frac{d \log(f(u))}{du}\bigg)^2 x_i'\Big)\Bigg]^{-1}\Bigg)$

Indeed, if $f(u)$ is Gaussian, then

$\mathbb{E}\Bigg(\Big(\frac{d\log(f(u))}{du}\Big)^2 \Bigg) = \mathbb{E}\Big(\frac{u^2}{\sigma^4} \Big) = 1/\sigma^2$,

which would take us to the previous case of OLS. I would feel happy answering at least the first part of item f), which asks us to compare these asymptotic variances. However, I don't see how to do it because we don't have so much structure on $f$. Any ideas on how to it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually the asymptotic distributions you wrote are all incorrect. I think you meant $$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta} - \beta ^{\ast
}) \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \sigma^2(x^T x)^{-1})$$

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Well, if $f$ is a Gaussian pdf, then $\log f(u) = c - \frac{u^2}{2\sigma^2}$. Then the result follows, doesn't it?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi but how come the distribution has a 1x1 asymptotic variance? Is your $x$ a matrix?

Comment: All i'm saying is if $x = [x_1 \ldots x_n]$, i.e. your observed samples, then the asymptotic distribution on the OLS estimator (given zero mean and iid $u_i$'s of course) is as I mentioned above. What you wrote doesn't make sense because according to your writing, you say that the asymptotic distribution on the OLS estimator depends on $x_i$ !!!! which $x_i$ ? $x_1$ ? $x_n$ ? any ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi yes, since they are iid it makes no difference! There is a slight confusion on notation however, I believe. The full model I have in mind is $y = X\beta + u$ where $X$ is a $n \times k$ matrix and $\beta$ is $k \times 1$. So, $X'u$, for example, can be seen as $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}u_i x_i$, where $x_i$ is a $k \times 1$ vector. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Moreover, you seem to consider a fixed $x$. This model should use the stochastic independent variable framework, right?

Comment: your likelihood is $f(y \vert x, \beta,\sigma^2)$. $x$ should not be regarded as stochastic. Also, the essence of the problem lies in $\beta$, and not $\sigma^2$ nor $x$; therefore you can assume them to be known. Also if $x$ and $\beta$ are unknown then your problem is underdetermined. In slang language: "how would you observe $N$ samples in $y$ and estimate $N+1$ parameters, $x$ and $\beta$ ?"

Comment: [cont'd]..  "you can not do so in the absence of noise.. I would love to learn how you'd estimate $N+1$ parameters from noisy measurements"

Comment: @AhmadBazzi ok, cool. Let's assume they are known, I agree with you. But you would still have to compute the expectation of that derivative and compare it to the other distribution. How would you do it?

Comment: We're not done with the OLS distribution you've written.. You agree it's wrong, no ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi once we maintain $x$ fixed, the distribution should have asymptotic variance equal to $\sigma^2 B^{-1}$, where $B = \lim (1/n) X'X$, which agrees with your comment. I agree its wrong in this sense.